# Flask routing logic

Tags: python, flask, logical-operators, execution

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the logic of flask routing. For example, the snippet below could handle a registration form. The tricky (for me) part is that the `form.validate_on_submit()` logic is *before* the template rendering. That is, when a user gets the chance to submit something in the form, the function is already in the return statement, past the `form.validate_on_submit()` logic.

Nevertheless, it this example still works. I would like to understand how can the logic in the function be executed even after its return statement has been reached.

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('success'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key concept here is the `if` conditional.

What you are missing out on is the fact that `form.validate_on_submit` is a *convenience function* which is equivalent to saying

```py
if request.method=="POST" and form.validate():
    # ...
```

You can see an example where this is shown [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/#in-the-view)

When the page is first loaded, it is with a *GET* request. We execute the first line `form = ContactForm()` and, since our conditional does *not evaluate to True* **which it will not since it is not a POST request**, we go to the last line and render the HTML template, passing in the form.

Now, once the page is displayed to the user and they submit the form, we send a request to the **same route as before, but with a POST request**. Now, we can validate the form and assuming everything checks out, we can fire off the redirect.

Hope that help, it can definitely be a bit confusing before you really get comfortable with what you're looking at!

Comment: Thank you! What I didn't realize is that after submission, the request goes to *the same route* but as a POST request. Now it all clicked for me.